# High charts multiple values in X-axis

Tags: highcharts

I need to display multiple set of values in High charts x-axis.[Please find image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r87ee.png).

Comment: Hi @Prashanth, You just need to use multiple series. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/u0tsn1p7/

Comment: Ya that i have plotted. My question is abt the values that need to be displayed on x-axis, ie. on x-axis i need to display time and value from 1 to 93

Comment: Hi i need to plot or display both time and value in x-axis like we have secondary and ternary y-axis. in the same way i need x-axis to display both values. Please let me know the solution that can display both values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `formatter` function to add some additional values to labels:

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    labels: {
        rotation: 90,
        formatter: function() {
            return 'additionalValue ' + Highcharts.dateFormat(
                this.dateTimeLabelFormat,
                this.pos
            )
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ktbnq0uw/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek. I need to display values separately in x-axis as shown in the image. please let me know is it possible to display values as show in image attached. Thank you for the response.

Comment: Hi @Prashanth, By using `formatter` function, you can display any additional information. What exactly value do you want to display? http://jsfiddle.net/agw89p3v/

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek thanks for you answer but my question is how can i display multiple series of data in x-axis, like we display time block in x-axis i need to display other set of values in x-axis. Please check image i need to display values in x-axis as shown in image ----  **https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgjXh.png**

Comment: Hi @Prashanth, You can also use multiple `xAxis`. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/03aL7whx/. Is this the result you want to get?